# Cache Optimization and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr

Suppose I have a calculator class that implements the Strategy Pattern using `std::function` objects as follows (see Scott Meyers, Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs):

```
class Calculator
{
public:
  ...
  std::vector<double> Calculate(double x, double y)
  {
     std::vector<double> res;
     for(const Function& f : functions)
        res.push_back(f(x,y));
     return res;
  }

private:
  std::vector<Function> functions;
};
```

where

```
typedef std::function<double(double,double)> Function;
```

Here is the problem I am facing: suppose functions `f` and `g`, both of type `Function`, perform expensive and identical calculations internally to get the final result. In order to improve efficiency, one could wrap all the common data in a `struct`, compute it once and provide to them as an argument. However, this design has several flaws. For example, this would cause a change in the signature of `Function`, which can result in unnecessary arguments being passed to some function implementations. Moreover, these common and internal data are no longer hidden from other components in the code, which can harm code simplicity.

I would like to discuss the following optimization strategy: implement a class `CacheFG` that:

1. Define a `Update` method that calculates its internal data with a given pair of doubles `x` and `y`; and
2. Define a `Check` method to determine if its current internal data was calculated with a given pair of doubles `x` and `y`.

What one could do then is to make `f` and `g` to share a common instance of the class `CacheFG`, which could be done using the `std::shared_ptr` construct. So, below would be the creation of `f` and `g` functions using auxiliary functions `f_aux` and `g_aux`.

```
double f_aux(double x, double y, const std::shared_ptr<CacheFG>& cache)
{
   if(not cache->Check(x,y))
      cache->Update(x,y);
   ...
}

std::shared_ptr<CacheFG> cache;
Function f = std::bind(f_aux, _1, _2, cache);
Function g = std::bind(g_aux, _1, _2, cache);
```

My questions are: (1) is this a safe approach for optimization? (2) is there a better approach for solving this problem?

Edit: After a few answers, I found out that my intention here is to implement a *memoization technique* in C++. I remark that only the last calculated state is enough for my purposes.

---

Thanks to *DeadMG*, I will now write here just an improvement over his approach. His idea consists of using a memoization technique with [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). I just offer a slight modification, where I use the construct `std::decay<Args>::type` to ensure the definition of a `tuple` with non-reference types only. Otherwise, functions with const-reference arguments would cause compilation errors.

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
std::function<Ret(Args...)> MemoizeLast(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f)
{
    std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...> cache;
    Ret result = Ret();
    return [=](Args... args) mutable -> Ret
    {
        if(std::tie(args...) == cache)
            return Ret(result);
        cache = std::make_tuple(args...);
        return result = f(args...);
    };
}
```

In order to prevent the move of `result`, a copy of it is returned (`return Ret(result)`) when the provided `args` is the one cached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why create your own class? There's no need for you to fail to re-create the interface of `unordered_map`.  This functionality can be added as a re-usable algorithm based on `std::function` and `std::unordered_map`. It's been a while since I worked with variadic templates, but I hope you get the idea.

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args> 
std::function<Ret(Args...)> memoize(std::function<Ret(Args...)> t) {
    std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Args...>, Ret> cache;
    return [=](Args... a) mutable -> Ret {
        if (cache.find(std::make_tuple(a...)) != cache.end())
            return cache[std::make_tuple(a...)];
        else
            return cache[std::make_tuple(a...)] = t(a...);
    };
}
```

I don't recall, offhand, whether `std::hash` natively supports tuples. If not, you might need to add it, or use `std::map` which does natively support them.

Edit: Hmm, I didn't notice that you wanted to *share* the cache. Well, this shouldn't be too difficult a problem, just stick an `unordered_map` member in Calculator and pass it in by reference, but the semantics of doing so seem a bit... odd.

Edit again: Just the most recent value? Even simpler.

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args> 
std::function<Ret(Args...)> memoize_last(std::function<Ret(Args...)> t) {
    std::tuple<Args...> cache;
    Ret result;
    return [=](Args... a) mutable -> Ret {
        if (std::tie(a...) == cache)
            return result;
        cache = std::make_tuple(a...);
        return result = t(a...);
    };
}
```

If you want to share between several Functions, then the alteration is the same- just declare it in the class and pass in as reference.

Comment: Nobody talks about internal implementation

Comment: It has, by about a billion miles, the cleanest simplest interface *and* implementation.

Comment: @DeadMG I don't need to create a history of all past evaluations; that is, the cache only needs to store only one state that corresponds to arguments `x` and `y`. So, is it still necessary the `unordered_map`?

Comment: No. You can fairly simply modify it to perform something like that.

Comment: @DeadMG Great solution; I using it now. Please, correct just a small thing: replace `-> Ret mutable` to `mutable -> Ret`. Thanks.

Comment: @DeadMG Here is an issue I am facing. Once the line `return result` is executed, all the contents in `result` is moved by automatic forwarding. Then, the next time the memoized function is invoked with the same arguments, the `result` variable is empty. How do I fix this behavior? I want `result` as a permanent copy as long as the line `return result = t(a...)` is not executed.

Comment: Result shouldn't be moved. That's probably a compiler defect- you should submit it to your compiler vendor. However, you can simply cast it to a `Ret&`, that should eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Before optimizing - measure. Then if you really perform many calculations with same value - then create this cache object. I'd like to hide cache checking and updating in  `CacheFG::get(x, y)` and use it like `const auto value = cache->get(x,y)`.

Comment: Agree, profile before optimizing. What I can tell you now is that this is necessary, because if I know this approach can be implemented, the _actual_ signature of my functions will be simpler. The simplification in getting the cache data is welcome.

Comment: Ho boy. Do not use a singleton. Do not create your own crappy interface. Just use the components provided to you as Standard.

Comment: @DenisErmolin No singleton. I just need an object that will compute its internal data once, which will be reused in subsequent calls in a loop (see `Calculator::Calculate`).